# Data Structure for supporting certain operations in O(log n) time

Tags: algorithm, avl-tree

Consider storing  **tuples (id, date , views)** in some data structure supporting the operations 
**insert(id, date, views)** - inserts the element in the data structure and if the elements
if already there it simply update the views. So each **id** will be unique storing the **date** and **view**. 
Only the **views** get updated. 
**delete(id)** - remove the element with corresponding id
**search(id)** - returns the corresponding tuple with corresponding id
**findelementWithMaxView(date)** - consider all tuples which have the second part (`date`) 
greater than or equal to **date** (**parameter**) return anyone with maximum views.

What Data structure we can make that could support all these operations in O(log(n)) time

**My Thougths :** 
We could simply make an AVL tree with key as **postId**. That would support insert, delete and search
in O(log n). But just making this wont help with **findelementWithMaxView(date)** function in O(log n)

If I make another AVL tree with key as **date** and each node of the tree stores an extra information 
That is the **(max-views, id)** where **max-view** is the maximum of views for the subtree with that node
and id is the id of the tuple with the max-views. 
Not sure if this would do all the operations in O(log n)

Answer (score 1):

#### Your line of thinking is correct - with a caveat

You line of thinking is correct. Having two data structures with O(log(n)) that are modified at every step will result in the complexity of O(log(n) + log(n)) which is still O(log(n)).

- **Insert(id):** Insert (id, date, views) into first structure with id as key - log(n). Find the date key in the second structure and replace id, views if needed - log(n). So insert is ok.
- **Search(id):** log(n), nothing else needed - ok.
- **Update(id):** log(n) for search, then update the views. This means that we will need to perform search in the secondary structure to update the max-views and id if necessary. Since we are likely only ever going to increase the view count I will give you a bit of a leeway to say this is log(n).
- **FindElementWithMaxDate(date)** thanks to the secondary structure, this will be manageable within the log(n).

Now here is an interesting question that wasn't covered: **Are the dates unique?** If yes, then everything is nice, delete works and we can all go and sing kumbaya. 
However I'm somewhat convinced that it isn't the case - if the dates were unique, it wouldn't be necessary to have separate date and id. (Though it might still be useful, probably a good practice?) After a bit of thinking I arrived at a conclusion that both scenarios are possible. So what happens if the dates aren't unique?

**If the dates aren't unique, the delete/decrease breaks.**
Since we only store the (max-views, id) in our secondary structure, we are in trouble. The delete of the max-views leaves us with the impossible task of finding the 2nd-max without any preparation. So we will have to go through all the elements with our **date** - and there can be up to O(n) of them.<sup>1</sup>

So what can be done about that?
Since the ID's are unique, use the ID's as a tie breaker. So we have an AVL tree with date as a key, id as a tiebreaker. Furthermore, every node of the tree needs to hold the maximum_views(node, left_subtree, right_subtree) so that we can quickly answer the question for an interval of dates<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup> On average there will be O(sqrt(n)) of them. Which is not that bad, however it is worse than the O(log(n)) we wanted. 
<sup>2</sup> Which is [date: last_date] in our case.

Comment: Yes dates need not be unique. So what I understand is you are storing all tuples for a date in the single node in the secondary AVL tree. And storing them in heap with key as `views`. But the function `findelementWithMaxView` >=certain-date still wont work in O(log n) time.  So apart from the heap we would also need to store the (max-views,id) of a subtree inside a node. Correct me. This is getting little bit confusing ...

Comment: Ah, yes. It got confusing so I forgot that one part. Storing the max(subtree) in the root of each heap will be necessary. Then when you update any of the heaps in a way that changes the max, you will need to bubble the new maximum upwards to the root. Let me edit the answer.

Comment: If the dates aren't unique then you can just use the ID to break ties.

Comment: True that. I likely overcomplicated this ^^.

Comment: Oh yeah I think that nails it. So simply using the (date,id) as key in secondary AVL tree so everything would be possible in O(log n). And we will still be storing the extra information {max-view, id} in each node.